# Google charts floating min / max / average column chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to create a Google chart that looks like the following:

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=200x125&chd=t2:10,50,60,80,40%7C50,60,100,40,20%7C30,70,90,95,45&chco=4d89f900,c6d9fd&chbh=20&chds=0,160&chm=H,336699,2,-1,1:22

Basically, I just want to represent the max, min, and average all on one chart, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I know it's possible using markers with the old URL-based charts, but they're being deprecated and it doesn't look like the new API supports markers yet.

I tried using candlesticks, but the only way I got it working was with a skinny line and a horizontal line in the middle, so it looked like a bunch of plus signs rather than floating columns with line markers.  I know I could also technically stack a column chart with a stepped area chart, but then the line is continuous across all entries, which I don't want.

Thanks.

EDIT: Using jmac's method and intervals, I came up with this:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'label');
  data.addColumn('number', 'filler');
  data.addColumn('number', 'range');
  data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addRows([
    ['A', 3, 4, 2],
    ['B', 2, 5, 4],
    ['C', 4, 4, 1],
    ['D', 5, 2, 1],
    ['E', 1, 8, 4],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    width: 600,
    isStacked: true,
    series: [{color:'transparent'},{color:'silver'},{color:'silver'}],
    vAxis: {gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}, textPosition: 'none'},
    focusTarget: 'category',
    intervals: { 'style': 'bars', 'barWidth': 1.3, 'lineWidth': 2 },
  });
}
```

I don't have enough reputation to post an image of what it looks like yet, but if you paste it in here you can see it: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart

Also, since it still highlights the filler area when you mouse over it, I found a css hack to hide the highlighting on mouse over:

```
#chart-div {
    svg g g g g rect {
      stroke-width:0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Intervals](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals) documentation.  The examples are all based on a LineChart, but they can be used with many of the different chart types.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried using intervals with a candlestick chart but they weren't working. They worked if I used a column chart, but then the min and max weren't "floating" unless I added a dummy entry underneath the data and matched the background color.  The column chart hack still showed up in the legend and the area was highlighted on hover, which I don't want.

Comment: You can remove the hacked series from the legend and make it disappear so it doesn't interact by setting the `series.<series index>` options like this: `{color: 'transparent', visibleInLegend: false, enableInteractivity: false}`.  I'll write up an answer with an example.

Comment: I came up with a better way, see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "box" style intervals to accomplish what you want:

```
function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Min');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Average');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Max');

    data.addRows([
        ['Foo', 3, 5, 7],
        ['Bar', 5, 8, 10],
        ['Baz', 0, 2, 6],
        ['Bat', 1, 2, 4]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    // duplicate 1 column as a dummy data series, and add intervals to it
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        id: 'min',
        type: 'number',
        role: 'interval',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 1);
        }
    }, {
        id: 'avg',
        type: 'number',
        role: 'interval',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 2);
        }
    }, {
        id: 'max',
        type: 'number',
        role: 'interval',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 3);
        }
    }, 1, 2, 3]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        lineWidth: 0,
        intervals: {
            style: 'boxes'
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                // dummy data series, controls color of intervals
                visibleInLegend: false,
                color: 'blue',
                enableInteractivity: false
            },
            1: {
                // min series options
            },
            2: {
                // average series options
            },
            3: {
                // max series options
            }
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/pvJpx/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  I didn't see it until I had gotten the other solution working, but it looks like this would also work just as well.

Comment: This is the proper answer. Boy do I feel silly for forgetting about the interval options.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is how it looks visually, you can recreate this with a bit of finagling to have it look like this:

[image: sample chart]

This is the code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['label', 'filler', 'bot half', 'top half'],
    ['A', 3, 2, 2],
    ['B', 2, 4, 1],
    ['C', 4, 1, 3],
    ['D', 5, 1, 1],
    ['E', 1, 4, 4],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    width: 600,
    isStacked: true,
    series: [{color:'transparent'},{color:'silver'},{color:'silver'}],
    vAxis: {gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}, textPosition: 'none'},
    focusTarget: 'category',
  });
}
```

This is a dumb workaround, but here are the steps given a `min` value, a `max` value, and an `avg` value:

1. Create a dummy (transparent) series equal to `min`
2. Create a second series for the bottom half of the bar equal to `avg` - `min`
3. Create a third series for the top half of the bar equal to `max` - `avg`

Although it *looks* right, the issue is that interaction with the chart will be real funky, in the sense that it won't show you what you would expect from the chart (you would have separate values that aren't showing min, max, and average, but only two values for the size of points 2) and 3) above). You can get around this with creative use of `focusTarget`, but that will still get you odd stuff like this:

[image: On Mouseover]

Now you could theoretically rename your series, and use the `{v:, f:}` trick to make it look nicer, and that may be a good workaround, but it is very kludgy depending on your application. If you finagle it all nice and right, you would get something like this:

[image: Revised Mouseover]

This is done with the following code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Series Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Average');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Minimum');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Maximum');
  data.addRows([
    ['A', {v:3, f:'5'}, {v:2, f:'3'}, {v:2, f:'7'}],
    ['B', {v:2, f:'6'}, {v:4, f:'2'}, {v:1, f:'7'}],
    ['C', {v:4, f:'5'}, {v:1, f:'4'}, {v:3, f:'8'}],
    ['D', {v:5, f:'6'}, {v:1, f:'5'}, {v:1, f:'8'}],
    ['E', {v:1, f:'5'}, {v:4, f:'1'}, {v:4, f:'9'}],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    width: 600,
    isStacked: true,
    series: [{color:'transparent'},{color:'silver'},{color:'silver'}],
    vAxis: {gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}, textPosition: 'none'},
    focusTarget: 'category',
  });
}
```

Again, this is kludgy and not perfect (see the grey box around the filler series, that can't be helped), but it will display the info, and it can be automated using some fancy javascript and/or formatters with dataviews depending on how often the charts need to be changed and what format you get your data in.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  I got it working using your method plus intervals so that the dividing average line is more pronounced.

Comment: @user, thanks for accepting my answer, but the other solution posted works far better without some of the ugliness. I really suggest you try getting that one working (it works as written, and looks far better).

Comment: I just changed the accepted answer for anyone who ends up finding this in the future.